# MSBuild Event after Publish VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, publish, target

So I have problems finding a target that executes **AFTER** I have published.

I have a web application and I use one click publish to the filesystem.

In my proj file I have:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

I then want to do a simple copy task after publishing to the filesystem:

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishActions" AfterTargets="AfterPublish" >

<Message Text="--After Publish--" />
<ItemGroup>
  <ConfigurationFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)/MyFolder/**/*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ConfigurationFiles)" DestinationFolder="C:\Temp\" />
```

This works for many targets but not for AfterPublish or MSDeployPublish. 
Are these old targets no longer supported? What can I use instead?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: If it helps, use AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish" to execute the target after gathering files to publish. Came across this post while trying to find out how to execute after the files have actually been copied!

Comment: I want to note heavily that (after hours of researching) that @getsetcode is correct when using the `AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish"`